# Parameterized pipeline build to build more than one job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Parameterized pipeline job has to take more than one job name as parameter and start parameterized jobs in parallel, I tried below code but it isnt working

```
    def String[] jobs;
    stages {
      stage('stage1') {
        steps {
          script {
            jobs = jobnames.split(',');
            for (ii = 0; ii < jobs.size(); ii++) {
                build job: 'startjob_${jobs[ii]}', parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH',value: String.valueOf(BRANCH)),string(name: 'CHANGENUM',value: String.valueOf(CHANGENUM))]
            }
```

This code is working, but not the way I expected, I want to start all jobs in parallel. but its scheduling one job after other.
can anyone help me with this

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Hi @ANILMAHAPATRAOfficial I am able to make it work now, I updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
builds = [:]
for (ii = 0; ii < jobs.size(); ii++) {
    builds << [
            "startjob_${jobs[ii]}": { ->
                build job: "startjob_${jobs[ii]}", parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value: String.valueOf(BRANCH)), string(name: 'CHANGENUM', value: String.valueOf(CHANGENUM))]
            }
    ]
}
parallel builds
```

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: xyz for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)

Comment: @no1 it's not related to the code above. You are trying to access variable `xyz` somewhere which does not exist.

Comment: its a job name, i am trying to build xyz. Its inside jobs array